# Обобщение тернарного поиска

Tags: алгоритм

[Троичный поиск](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) - метод нахождения минимума(максимума) функции одной переменной. 
Как его удобней применить к функции 2х переменных?

Comment: просто параллельно обрабатывать сразу две переменные. Либо попеременно. В этом случае область поиска будет не отрезок, а "прямоугольник".
Конечно, это будет работать не для всех функций, а только в том случае, если предполагаемый минимум/максимум лежит внутри заданных границ и там нет "седла".

Comment: так можно?
Пусть есть f(x,y) - мат. функция 2х переменных.
searchV(valX,L,R,EPS) - функция которая ищет значение максимума функции f(x,y) по y, подставляя вместо x значение valX.
search(L,R,EPS){ - функция возвращает значение максимума функции f(x,y)
searchV(valX,L,R,EPS){
...while (L-R <EPS){
.....a = (2L+R)/3;
.....b = (L+2R)/3;
.....if (f(valX,a)>f(valX,b)){
.......r = b;
.....}else {
.......l = a;
.....}
...}
return f(valX,a);
}

Comment: Вообще-то поиск экстремума функции нескольких переменных -- весьма нехилая тема вычислительной математики.